# Need to refresh page to make jquery work

Tags: jquery

I found a jquery script online to vertical align content. However, when I resize the browser windows I need to refresh the page to make the jquery script work once again. Below you can find my code. I really appreciate any help. I'm a newbie to the javascript scene. Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>vAlign Test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style media="all">
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

    nav{
        height: 20%;
        background-color: red;
    }

    .container{
        height: 60%;
        background-color: orange;
    }

    .valignmiddle{
    }

    .fleft{
        width: 50%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding-left: 2%;
        text-align: justify;
        float: left;
    }

    .flright{
        width: 50%;
        float: right;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding-left: 2%;
    }

    footer{
        height: 20%;
        background-color: purple;
    }

</style>

</head>
<body>
<nav></nav>
<div class="container" style="width: 100%; height: 60%;">
<div class="valignmiddle">
   <section class="fleft">
    <h3>Contact me</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore cupiditate eligendi, eos voluptas pariatur quisquam facilis, laboriosam laudantium sint fuga, praesentium eveniet suscipit deleniti delectus quo quidem veritatis? Ratione, atque?</p>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore cupiditate eligendi, eos voluptas pariatur quisquam facilis, laboriosam laudantium sint fuga, praesentium eveniet suscipit deleniti delectus quo quidem veritatis? Ratione, atque?</p>
                   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore cupiditate eligendi, eos voluptas pariatur quisquam facilis, laboriosam laudantium sint fuga, praesentium eveniet suscipit deleniti delectus quo quidem veritatis? Ratione, atque?</p>
                       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore cupiditate eligendi, eos voluptas pariatur quisquam facilis, laboriosam laudantium sint fuga, praesentium eveniet suscipit deleniti delectus quo quidem veritatis? Ratione, atque?</p>
                           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore cupiditate eligendi, eos voluptas pariatur quisquam facilis, laboriosam laudantium sint fuga, praesentium eveniet suscipit deleniti delectus quo quidem veritatis? Ratione, atque?</p>
                               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore cupiditate eligendi, eos voluptas pariatur quisquam facilis, laboriosam laudantium sint fuga, praesentium eveniet suscipit deleniti delectus quo quidem veritatis? Ratione, atque?</p>
                                   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore cupiditate eligendi, eos voluptas pariatur quisquam facilis, laboriosam laudantium sint fuga, praesentium eveniet suscipit deleniti delectus quo quidem veritatis? Ratione, atque?</p>
                                       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore cupiditate eligendi, eos voluptas pariatur quisquam facilis, laboriosam laudantium sint fuga, praesentium eveniet suscipit deleniti delectus quo quidem veritatis? Ratione, atque?</p>
                                           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore cupiditate eligendi, eos voluptas pariatur quisquam facilis, laboriosam laudantium sint fuga, praesentium eveniet suscipit deleniti delectus quo quidem veritatis? Ratione, atque?</p>
                                               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore cupiditate eligendi, eos voluptas pariatur quisquam facilis, laboriosam laudantium sint fuga, praesentium eveniet suscipit deleniti delectus quo quidem veritatis? Ratione, atque?</p>
                                                   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore cupiditate eligendi, eos voluptas pariatur quisquam facilis, laboriosam laudantium sint fuga, praesentium eveniet suscipit deleniti delectus quo quidem veritatis? Ratione, atque?</p>
                                                       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore cupiditate eligendi, eos voluptas pariatur quisquam facilis, laboriosam laudantium sint fuga, praesentium eveniet suscipit deleniti delectus quo quidem veritatis? Ratione, atque?</p>



    </section>

    <div class=" flright">
    <h3>aapen</h3>    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit unde nisi a explicabo perspiciatis corrupti exercitationem temporibus autem odit asperiores molestias, facere rerum error nostrum in. Architecto natus inventore, voluptates.</p>
</div>

</div>


</div>

<footer></footer>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
    $('.valignmiddle').each(function() {
        $(this).parent().css('position', 'relative');
        $(this).css('position', 'absolute');
        $(this).css('top', '50%');
        $(this).css('left', '0px');
        $(this).css('width', '100%');
    });
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var thisheight = Math.round(parseInt($('.valignmiddle').outerHeight()) / 2);
        $('.valignmiddle').css('margin-top', '-' + thisheight + 'px');
        if(parseInt($('.valignmiddle').outerHeight()) > parseInt($('.valignmiddle').parent().outerHeight())) {

            $('.valignmiddle').parent().outerHeight($('.valignmiddle').outerHeight());

        }
    }).trigger('resize');
});
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code is working fine without need of refresh, check by console.log() in resize function

Answer (score 0):

You can try with onresize event on body tag to call your javascript function.

example:-  `<body onresize="myFunction()">`

In myFunction you can write your code for alignment. Using this you need not to refresh page on resizing window.

Answer (score 0):

**Using jquery for this is pointless ...**

Instead of giving you what you want, I will give you what you need...the best way to vertical align something is like this (PS: I couldn't find a browser that doesn't support this, tested it in IE8 too);

You can see it in action [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/orgcafcg/)

**CSS only solution**

```
#yourdiv{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
}
```

The above will keep your div centered vertically even if you resize your screen.

Also, if you want absolute center, just add left and right parameters, like so:

```
#yourdiv{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  margin:auto;
}
```